# How can I enter input successfully after writing the plt.show() line in a while loop?

Tags: python-3.8

As a beginner in Python3, I’ve been following the Python Crash Course book. The following code prints the graph but does not ask for an input as intended. I have tried placing plt.show() after the if statement but the program ends up loading for a long time, eventually failing to display the graph. Is there a way to fix this?

## Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from random_walk import RandomWalk


while True:
    rw = RandomWalk()
    rw.fill_walk()
    plt.style.use('classic')
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    point_numbers = range(rw.num_points)
    ax.scatter(rw.x_values, rw.y_values,c=point_numbers, cmap=plt.cm.Blues, edgecolors='none', s=15)




    plt.show()
```

## The program does not print the following for input

```
    keep_running = input("Make another walk? (y/n):")

    if keep_running == 'n':
        break
```

## The following is saved on a separate file

```
from random import choice

class RandomWalk:
    def __init__(self, num_points=5000):
        """Initialize attributes of a walk"""
        self.num_points = num_points
        self.x_values = [0]
        self.y_values = [0]

   def fill_walk(self):
       """ calculating all the points in the walk"""

       # Keep taking steps until the walk reaches the desired length.
       while len(self.x_values) < self.num_points:
           # Decide which direction to go and how far to go in that direction.
           x_direction = choice([1,-1])
           x_distance = choice([0,1,2,3,4])
           x_step = x_direction*x_distance

           y_direction = choice([1,-1])
           y_distance = choice([0,1,2,3,4])
           y_step = y_direction*y_distance

           # Reject moves that go nowhere
           if x_step == 0 and y_step == 0:
               continue

           # Calculate the new position
           x = self.x_values[-1] + x_step 
           y = self.y_values[-1] + y_step

           self.x_values.append(x)
           self.y_values.append(y)
```

Comment: It will help us if you show your full code as one snippet.

Comment: I have edited it to show the full code. Thanks for having a look.

Comment: Well at my pc this program works perfectly. If you put the question after the plot.show() you should first close the plot that appears and then the program will ask the user to continue or not.

Comment: The question comes up immediately after I hit the close button but the plot loads for a long time and does not end up closing. Would the problem be due to eg processing speed on my Mac?

Comment: You can see how much CPU and memory your program consumes by opening the Activity Monitor. You can find Activity Monitor by clicking the "Finder" on your dock to open a Finder window. Click "Applications" on the sidebar of the Finder window to see your Mac applications. In this folder, double-click the "Utilities" folder. Double-click the "Activity Monitor" icon to access the application.

Comment: Thank you very much!